# APC: opcode cache vs. user cache - set separate limits

Tags: php, caching, apc, opcode-cache

I am trying to move from the typical combination of APC (for opcode) and Memcache (for my userdata) to a purely apc based cache.  Given my usage structure it makes sense and performance is higher.

But unlike before, where the apc cache was limited to a reasonable size and did not affect my data cache, I am now worried that the opcode cache might grow relatively large so that the sum of opcode cache an datacache exceeds the limit.  As far as I understand, this would result in a flush of the total cache.

Is there a way to mimic the behaviour, as if apc was only an opcode cache and limit the opcode cache size to a reasonable limit, leaving the rest for user data?

Or should I try setting lower ttl values for the opcode cache, so it always gets flushed first?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, that my question is irrelevant.  Due to the cache fragmentation problems, the cache is quickly marked as full.  (see other posts on stackoverflow).  As a consequence apc user cache should only be used selectively.